# How to read response header returned by asmx web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, pass-by-reference, soapheader

I'm making an asmx web service in C# and trying to test it with a simple client app. I write the web service's inner code but I have to conform to a given xml for post and response. It's supposed to receive a header with authentication information and return a token and comments. The headers in both directions contain the same types but half the fields are used only for input and half are used only for output.

The header class is defined roughly like this:

```
public class CustomHeader : SoapHeader
{
     public string InParam;
     public string OutParam;
}
```

The web service method code looks something like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class WebService_UD : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
     public CustomHeader customHeader;

     [WebMethod]
     [SoapHeader("customHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
     public string CustomWebMethod (int param1, string param2)
     {
         // code reading inner fields of customHeader
         // code updating other inner fields of customHeader
         // code dealing with other parameters and creating normal   return value
     }
 }
```

And the test client application like this:

```
     WebService_UDClient caller = new WebService_UDSoapClient();
     CustomHeader header = new CustomHeader();
     header.InParam = "blip";
     string response = caller.CustomWebMethod(header, 1, "1");
     string outParam = header.OutParam; // returns null here
```

The web service doesn't seem to change the header. Changing the header's InParam also doesn't change it in client. The problem is probably that I'm not passing header in by reference, but I don't know how to change the web service code (since the rest is auto-generated) to pass by reference.

So how do I do that, or how do I retrieve the response header in some other way?

Comment: In case someone had a similar issue, this eventually worked when I put the web service onto IIS on an actual server (autogenerated code passed the header parameter by ref), but not when on localhost (autogenerated code was different). No idea why.